# How copy down mockServiceWorker.js file in React application during Webpack build proces to my build folder

Tags: reactjs, graphql, msw

I try to setup [Mock Service Worker](https://mswjs.io/docs/) for my React project. My project doesn't use [CRA](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app).

I want to intercept GraphQL request and mock it's response for creating an end 2 end test with Cypress.

How do I copy down `mockServiceWorker.js` file to my build folder (using Webpack), like the other assets images and fonts and so on?

I used the command `npx msw init build --save`. Then the `mockServiceWorker.js` has been created.

But as soon as I run `npm start` and my client and server gets compiled the file `mockServiceWorker.js` disappears?

Also I need `msw` in the pipeline on our acceptance environment, to run the Cypress end 2 end test also in the pipeline.

Answer (score 5):

You don't necessarily need to copy the worker script. In most cases, you're using MSW as a development tool. If you involve webpack to serve your development bundle, you're likely to use [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) to serve that bundle. Webpack Dev Server supports the `static.directory` option (previously `contentBase` in webpack 4) that points to a local directory in your project that should act as the dev server's public directory. That's where you need to [initialize the worker into](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/browser#setup).

```sh
$ npx msw init ./public --save
```

If you indeed use Webpack Dev Server, then make sure you point it to the correct public directory. One of the ways to do this is in your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    }
  }
}
```

> Note that if you are already serving static assets, you don't have to add any additional webpack configurations. Simply initialize the worker via `npx msw init` into the same directory that contains your static assets.

If you're serving your webpack builds by some other means, you can utilize [copy-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) to explicitly copy the worker script from one location to another. However, I'm pretty sure the dev server suggestion above is what you seek.